# Apply OpenEmbedded patch for Buildroot

Tags: buildroot, openembedded

How I can modify patch created for OpenEmbedded to BuildRoot? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

What does this patch do? If it's a patch that modifies the source code of a given software component then it should be easy to adapt. If on the other hand it's a patch that adds a new package to OpenEmbedded, or modifies some OpenEmbedded recipe, then it cannot be used for Buildroot: OpenEmbedded and Buildroot are two quite different build systems.

That said, it's impossible to answer your question precisely if you don't provide more details. Could you point the specific patch you're refering to?